# Reinstall OS on Karbonn A1+

Tags: operating-system, stock-rom, karbonn-a1+

I have Karbonn A1+, android system of my phone totally hanged. i want format my phone and reinstall operating system. please suggest me method. (Android Operating System : Android 2.3 Gingerbread)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to void your warranty? If not, contact the Karbonn Customer Care and ask for the Official Flash Tool and a copy of the Stock ROM. Reboot your phone in recovery mode and reinstall the android using that tool.